hive on docker with GCS fails
I am trying to setup hive with GCS storage using these containers. But hitting the error

ERROR : FAILED: Execution Error, return code 40000 from
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask. MetaException(message:Got
exception: org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException No
FileSystem for scheme "gs")

The docker command that I use to create the container is
docker run -d -p 10000:10000 -p 10002:10002 --env SERVICE_NAME=hiveserver2 \
--env SERVICE_OPTS="-Dhive.metastore.uris=thrift://172.17.0.3:9083" \
--env HIVE_GCS_KEYFILE=/opt/hive/conf/key.json \
--env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/opt/hive/conf/key.json \
--env HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/opt/hive/lib/ \
--env HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH=$HIVE_AUX_JARS_PATH:/opt/hive/lib/ \
--mount type=bind,source=$PWD/core-site.xml,target=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml \
--mount type=bind,source=$PWD/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.8.jar,target=/opt/hive/lib/gcs-connector-hadoop3-2.2.8.jar \
--mount type=bind,source=$PWD/key.json,target=/opt/hive/conf/key.json \
--mount type=bind,source=$PWD/hive-log4j2.properties,target=/opt/hive/conf/hive-log4j2.properties \
--mount type=bind,source=$PWD/hive-site.xml,target=/opt/hive/conf/hive-site.xml \
--env IS_RESUME="true" \
--name hiveserver2-gcs apache/hive:4.0.0 

The metastore service is running on 172.17.0.3. Any suggestions on fixing this?

The following properties are set as part of hive-site.xml as well.
fs.gs.working.dir
fs.gs.impl
fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl
fs.gs.auth.service.account.enable
gs.auth.serviceAccountKeyFile
hive.aux.jars.path

When you're using $VAR in the Docker run, it's evaluating your local shell, not appending to the container existing variables... This will mess with the classpath and aux path
